# Python function to return row by based on most recent date, and active status

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
(df)
School ID      Num          Column 1     Column 2      Status       Modified Date
School 1       6000         NaN          NaN           Active       2020-07-18
School 2       3000TO4000   3000         4000          InActive     2020-09-05
School 3       9-999        NaN          NaN           Active       2020-03-30
School 4       8000TO9000   8000         9000          Active       2020-12-14
School 5       9-999        NaN          NaN           InActive     2020-10-21
....
```

I am trying to create a function that when a number is entered, it will check column 1 (string type) to see if there is a direct match, then return that school ID. If not it will check to see if the number is between the two numbers in columns 1 and 2 (floats).

However, there are some instances where there are duplicate numbers in column 1. So if 9-999 is entered, Schools 3 and 5 will be returned.

I need to create a function that would sort that result, and only return the value with the most recent Modified date, and if the Status is active.

So if 9-999 was entered, this result would be returned.

```
School ID      Num          Column 1     Column 2      Status       Modified Date
School 3       9-999        NaN          NaN           Active       2020-03-30
```

If 8099 was entered, this would be returned:

```
School ID      Num          Column 1     Column 2      Status       Modified Date
School 4       8000TO9000   8000         9000          Active       2020-12-14
```

This is the code I have now that works for just finding matches between Num, and Columns 1 and 2, but doesn't account for the duplicates. I'd prefer to use a sort function, but I'm not sure how to exactly.

```
s = '#Num'

q = df[df['School ID']==str(s)]

if len(q):
    print(q)
else:
    s = float(s)
    m = df[['Column 1', 'Column 2']].apply(lambda x: x['Column 1'] <= s <= x['Column 2'], axis=1)
    print(df[m])
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How is your `Split_df` defined? Do you want to check the column `Num` for a specific value? Maybe something with your description is wrong and you mean `Num` with the string value instead of column 1

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, Split_df should have been df1. I want to check column num for a specific match in strings, then if not, see if the number is in the range of columns 1 and 2. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will solve your problem. I made it a bit simpler by using the `loc` function of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = {'School ID': ["School 1", "School 2", "School 3", "School 4", "School 5"], 
    'Num': ["6000", "3000TO4000", "9-999", "8000TO9000", "9-999"], 
    'Column 1' : [np.NaN, 3000, np.NaN, 8000, np.NaN], 
    'Column 2' : [np.NaN, 4000, np.NaN, 9000, np.NaN], 
    'Status' : ['Active', 'InActive', 'Active', 'Active', 'InActive']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


search = "9-999"

try:
    int(search)
    check_col = df.loc[(df['Column 1'] <= int(search)) &  (df['Column 2'] >= int(search)) & (df['Status'] == 'Active')]
    if len(check_col) > 0:
        print(check_col)

except:
    pass

check_num = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Active') & (df['Num'] == str(search))]

if len(check_num) > 0:
        print(check_num)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much this worked! A question I have though, why would the conditions If or Else not be as good in this situation compared to try and except/pass.

Comment: My try/except only checks, if the input can be converted to an integer number. Because if your input is "9-999" you cannot search between the two values in Column1 and Column2. You can also use an if statement in the form of: `if type(search) == "int"` or something :)

Comment: I don't actually return the max date, was this a requirement? With the first statement `check_col ` i search if the value is between the two in the columns, with the second `check_num` i search if the value is in the `num`. If something is found somewhere (`len()  > 0`, it prints the found rows, if not (`len() == 0`) it doesnt.